# Checking if a Discrete Time Signal is Periodic

Tags: signal-processing, periodic-functions

I am trying to figure out if the following discrete time signal is periodic.

$$
x[n]=\sin((6\pi/7)n+1)
$$

I know that

> A DT signal x[n] is periodic if there exists a positive integer *N* such that 
>   $$x[n+N] = x[n], \forall n\in Z$$

However, I am having trouble figuring out where to begin.

I found this other question, but I am not sure they are considering that the signal is discrete: [Is signal periodic? What is the period?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/851324/is-signal-periodic-what-is-the-period) since the period is $7/3$, a non-integer value.

Plotting the function in mathematic shows that the period is around 7.

[image]

Thanks.

**Edit:** Added plot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the fundamental period of:

$$x[n] = \sin((6\pi/7)n+1)$$

First we set $(6\pi/7)n = 2\pi$

Then we solve for n to get:
$n = 7/3$

Since this is a discrete signal, we need the period to be an integer so, we multiply by 3 to get it to the nearest integer.

Hence,
the fundamental period is $7$